# Unable to locate package python3-pip in Dockerfile while having Universal Repos enabled

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, pip, dockerfile

I am trying to install python3 and pip.
So, I have a dockerfile
(I also tried with ubuntu:20.04)-

(Note- I have made the Dockerfile short, for full dockerfile you can see [here](https://pastebin.com/m2AML0S0))

```
FROM ubuntu:latest 

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository universe

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apt install -y python3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
```

But it always give me error-

```
 ---> Running in ba9f299b852b
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package python3-pip
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y install python3-pip' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

While finding more out in the error, I found out that while the universal repositories were added, python3-pip didnt got installed, while other things like `python3-sip` got installed.
How do I fix this error and why did it happened?

Answer (score 0):

The `software-properties-common` meta-packages installs a bunch of softwares that are not required in a docker image and make its the size quite huge.

This simpler Dockerfile does the job for me.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /app
#COPY . /app
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet \
        python3 \
        python3-pip \
 && apt-get clean all

RUN pip install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools

RUN pip --version  # just for test
```

Output:

```
STEP 1/5: FROM ubuntu:latest
STEP 2/5: WORKDIR /app
--> Using cache 9f1d34a70ba9e13074601d16456fda97b2de87a0be3b18ddc6963fb65aaee096
--> 9f1d34a70ba
STEP 3/5: RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet         python3         python3-pip  && apt-get clean all
[...]
STEP 4/5: RUN pip install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-58.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (946 kB)
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.0.2
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
    Can't uninstall 'pip'. No files were found to uninstall.
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 45.2.0
    Not uninstalling setuptools at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
    Can't uninstall 'setuptools'. No files were found to uninstall.
Successfully installed pip-21.3 setuptools-58.2.0
STEP 5/5: RUN pip --version
pip 21.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
COMMIT staskoverflow-ubuntu
--> 2498ddc1767
Successfully tagged localhost/staskoverflow-ubuntu:latest
2498ddc17672584d2dd38bf23ae63521d9adb43465cf8c7b415c33dc2aa0aa01
```

The tool `pip` is updated to the version 21.3 and the OS-provided one is not uninstalled (this is a pip feature).

Anyway this dockefile, more similar to yours, works too:

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet \
        software-properties-common \
 && add-apt-repository universe \
 && apt-get update \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet \
        python3 \
        python3-pip \
 && apt-get clean all

RUN pip install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
```

After adding the `universe` repository, you should run again `apt-get update` to retrieve the new lists of packages with the new apt configuration. This is the root cause of the problem I think.